# Okular Windows 10 not showing videos in PDF

Tags: windows-10, video, pdf, latex, okular

I'm creating a presentation using beamer. I've embedded a video in the pdf using `media9` package. I'm using Okular PDF viewer. In ubuntu, everything works fine i.e. I can see the video playing as soon as I open the page. But in windows, the area that is supposed to contain video is empty.

Is there any setting I need to change or install any plugin to enable Okular to play videos in Windows 10?

Note:

1. I installed Okular from Windows store.
2. I'm open to using any other PDF viewer as well.
3. I tried Adobe Reader, but it said "Acrobat has encountered an error while playing this media clip"